# Wordpress "This webpage is not available" all of a sudden

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a serious problem. I was editing my CSS template in my Wordpress site in the Editor, changing the padding configurations of a div. Then all of a sudden the site would no longer load. It keeps giving me the error "This webpage is not available" Like I don't have any connection. But I checked FB and all sorts of other sites and they are running. I checked to see if Worpress is down, it's not.

May I ask if there is any way I can get my site running again? I been slaving over this for days and in just an instant it's gone.

THe test site is: http://itdctest.comlu.com/

Comment: u actually linked us to the WP admin of the site? r u trying to get hacked?

Comment: Did you wait just a minute before posting this? The site loads just fine for me...

Comment: What's that awful popup on the admin site???

Comment: Oh, im temporarily putting it on a free hosting site for development... Would that be a problem?

Comment: Do correct me if im wrong, but without my username or password, hacing it would be difficult? No?

Comment: It seems to time out every time I try to load it.

Comment: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://itdctest.comlu.com/

If it fails for you then it means there is something going on on YOUR side. Try refreshing or switching your DNS.

Comment: It loads just fine from here. The theme is very poor though, this is 2015 you know. a fixed width with a float on the left is more like 2005.

Comment: Yep I see it. It works on other people's computers. Had to get a friend to screen shot it to me. It's broken. It wasn't supposed to float to the left like that.